# R: Convert type "List" to dataframe to convert to excel - Text Mining

Tags: r, excel, list, dataframe, text-mining

When trying to stem and tokenize my list of reviews, it will automatically make it a list. It is a "character" type variable at first, but when applying the following code it turns it into a "list":

```
reviews <- tokenize_word_stems(reviews)
```

I want to eventually convert this into excel, but my write_xlsx function can only convert dataframes, and not lists.

the rest of my code looks like this, but it goes "wrong" when trying to stem the words:

```
reviews <- readLines("Reviewlist.csv")
reviews <- gsub(pattern = "\\W", replace = " ", reviews)
reviews <- tolower(reviews)
reviews <- gsub(pattern="\\b[A-z]\\b{1}", replace=" ", reviews)
reviews <- stripWhitespace(reviews)
reviews <- removeWords(reviews, stopwords())
reviews <- tokenize_word_stems(reviews)
```

the file:

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not reproducible! However, have you tried `as.data.frame(reviews)`?

Comment: Is writing to xlsx vs csv a hard condition for you? Otherwise you could paste your list entries together, collapsing them with commas and use `writeLines` to create a csv file manually.. it might cause some trouble due to different line lengths, but it should load into excel just fine where you can split the row by comma.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a lorem-ipsum dummy input here, based on my assumption what your "Reviewlist.csv" seems to look like.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

stri_rand_lipsum(5) %>%
  writeLines("Reviewlist.csv")
```

Then, this here is just your original code without alterations, but using `dplyr` grammar and explicitly stating the libraries necessary:

```
library(tm)
library(tokenizers)

reviews <- readLines("Reviewlist.csv") %>%
  gsub(pattern = "\\W", replace = " ", .) %>%
  tolower() %>%
  gsub(pattern="\\b[A-z]\\b{1}", replace=" ", .) %>%
  stripWhitespace() %>%
  removeWords(stopwords()) %>%
  tokenize_word_stems()
```

Now, what you can do is to bind your list items into a dataframe before being able to write it as an xlsx-file:

```
library(purrr)
library(writexl)

reviews_df <- reviews %>%
    map_dfr(~ setNames(., sprintf("word_%04d", seq_along(.))))

reviews_df %>%
  write_xlsx("Reviewlist.xlsx")
```

And that might create a very wide xlsx for you.
No idea whether Excel really is able to open it, but there you go :)